# Shrinking extremely large window

Tags: macos, window-manager

I have a very large window on Mavericks. The window is so large that I can't seem to get the mouse to the lower right corner to shrink the size of the window. How can I reduce the size of this window? Is there some keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Can you not get to any edge of the window at all? Mac windows can be shrunk from any edge/corner since a couple of versions.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. Maybe it's particular to my app...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can see the top left corner of the window, there should be a Red, Yellow and Green circle.

[image]

If you click the Green circle, the window should resize so that its entirety is visible.  You can then drag any side or corner to the desired size.

Comment: they may be grey... if so, click the one with the +

Comment: Doh! Pretty sure I had seen that in the past. Knew it must be something simple - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative method, even though the first method works & was accepted as the correct answer... this also works for attached file-picker sheets where you cannot reach the red/yellow/green dots.

Shift/drag any visible edge of a window will simultaneously resize it from all sides except the side opposite to the drag; then enabling you to drag it to a new position.